# Way to remove all -viewDidUnload from project's view controllers

Tags: ios, regex, vim, batch-processing, viewdidunload

As Apple's Official Doc said:

> **-viewDidUnload** is deprecated in iOS 6.0. Views are no longer purged under low-memory conditions and so this method is never called.

Meanwhile, it's better to remove all `-viewDidUnload` implements from projects that the deployment target is iOS 6.0 or later. But removing it one by one is boring, especially you've hundreds of controllers & several projects.

So, is there any script or command that can do this batch job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out a command for Vim, I'm sure it'll make your life easier. ;)

Open Vim in desired root dir (generally, it'll be your root dir of your all controller files), press <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> to enter command-line mode, run the command below:

```
:args **/*.m | argdo %s/^-\ (void)viewDidUnload\_.\{-}}\n^$\n//ge | update
```

This will replace all

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  [super viewDidUnload];
  ...
}
// a blank line here
```

to empty, in other words, the `-viewDidUnload` snippet will be removed. **But note**, there's a blank line after the implement. If you don't want to include it, use

```
:args **/*.m | argdo %s/^-\ (void)viewDidUnload\_.\{-}}//ge | update
```

instead.

**Note**: This will include lib files as well when you're in your project's root dir. I suggest go to your Controllers' root dir, then all files & you will be happy with the result. ;)

---

#### Tip:

After that, you'd better check whether all `-viewDidUnload` were removed, run the command below on terminal of your desired root dir:

```
$ find . -type f -iname "*.m" -exec grep -i "viewDidUnload" {} +
```

It should result with no output. Otherwise, some targets missed, you can locate it easily cause it'll list all files that not managed correctly, then just remove it manually (This might happen if your `- (void)viewDidLoad` is `-(void)viewDidLoad` without a space, or something else).

Finally, you can run

```
$ git diff -b --color-words
```

to see the result. Enjoy it! ;)

---

#### Further reading about the command

- `args **/*.m`: Sets arglist to contain all .m files in current directory and it's subdirectories;
- `argdo`: Run the following command(s) on all arguments in arglist;
- `%s/^-\ (void)viewDidUnload\_.\{-}}\n^$\n//ge`: Vim RegEx to replace `-viewDidUnload` implement snippet to empty;

  - `\_.`: Find any character including end-of-line (linebreak).
  - `\{-}`: Match as few as possible (stopping at the first `}`, e.g. `\{-}h` will stop at the first `h`);
  - `}`: The last item to match;
  - `\n`: Line-break;
  - `^$\n`: blank line.
- `update`: Save modification only if the buffer has been modified.

---

#### Reference

- [Search Across Multiple Lines](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_across_multiple_lines)
- [Search and Replace in Multiple Buffers](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Search_and_replace_in_multiple_buffers)